# Flutter GetX, show loading spinner until API responds

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I am new with Getx. I have following controller

`auth_controller.dart`

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:myapp/Models/model_login.dart';
import 'package:myapp/Providers/common_api_provider.dart';
import 'package:get_storage/get_storage.dart';

class AuthenticationController extends GetxController {
  ModelLogin? userDetails;
  var processing = false.obs;
  var isLoggedIn = false.obs;
  var showPasswordReset = false.obs;
  var box = GetStorage();

  Future sendResetLink(String email) async {
    try {
      processing(true);
      // change(null, status: RxStatus.loading());
      var lang = box.read("lang");
      final res = await CommonApiProvider.resetPassword(email, lang);
      //change(null, status: RxStatus.success());
      processing(false);
      if (res != null) {
        return res["message"];
      } else {
        return "ErrorOccurred";
      }
    } catch (e) {
      processing(false);
      print(e);
      rethrow;
    } finally {
      processing(false);
    }
  }

  showPasswordBlock(bool show) {
    showPasswordReset(show);
  }
}
```

I have following view -

`login.dart`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:myapp/controllers/auth_controller.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const LoginPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final AuthenticationController loginController =
      Get.put(AuthenticationController());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: CustomColors.baseColor,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(Responsive.size(context, 1.5),
              Responsive.size(context, 1.5), Responsive.size(context, 1.5), 0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: Responsive.size(context, 40),
                child: Image.asset(
                  "assets/images/logo.png",
                  width: Responsive.size(context, 15),
                ),
              ),
              const Expanded(
                child: Obx(() {
                  return loginController.showPasswordReset == true
                      ? forgotPassword()
                      : loginForm();
                }),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }

  Widget forgotPassword(){
    //
  }
}
```

I have button called 'Reset Password' in `forgotPassowrd()`, and upon clicking, following code is executed.

```
 if (loginController.processing.value == true) { //here i want to show loading spinner
                          Get.defaultDialog(
                              title: "",
                              radius: 12,
                              contentPadding:
                                  EdgeInsets.all(24),
                              content: const Center(
                                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                              ));
                        } else {
                          String error = await loginController.sendResetLink(
                              _forgotPasswordEmailController.text);

                          if (error != "") {
                            Get.defaultDialog(
                              title: "Error",
                              middleText: error.tr,
                              radius: 12,
                              cancel: CustomButton(
                                text: 'Ok'.tr,
                                onPressed: () {
                                  Get.back();
                                },
                                backgroundColor:
                                    CustomColors.dialogCancelBtnColor,
                                foregroundColor: Colors.black87,
                              ),
                            );
                          }
                        }
```

Problem:

Upon clicking 'Reset password' button how do I show progress spinner on dialog until server responds with something. I tried above approach but didn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First inplace of replace var to RxBool in controller file like

```
RxBool processing = false.obs;
```

Also replace

```
processing(true);    To            processing.value = true;
```

OR

```
processing(false);   To            processing.value = false;
```

And in a LoginPage write your loader code where you want to show Loader. Like

```
Obx(() => loginController.processing.value ? 
          CircularProgressIndicator() : SizedBox()
    );
```

Comment: Thankx, but unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: You need to try with simple widget not in alertdailog

Comment: Ok, how do i do with Dialogs, because need to show that in dialog.

Comment: I think its not working in dailog but you can show in stack view and build your own dailog like design